# Simple Java program consumes huge amount of memory

Tags: java, heap-memory, runtime.exec

The following simple program consumes about 800-900 MB RAM on my company computer and also on other company computers.
I tried different java versions like 1.8.0_331 or AdoptOpenJDK11.
When I start notepad.exe instead of cmd.exe the program consumes only a few MB.
Visual VM profiler says that there is heap size about 500MB and used heap about 13MB.
On my private computer I can't reproduce this issue.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there anything else running in the JVM that is memory-hungry? If there is none, is there anything running on the command prompt (cmd.exe) process while this is running?

Comment: On machines with a lot of memory and a lot CPU cores, recent versions of Java will default to allocating a maximum heap of 25% of the total memory, and for machines with little memory, it defaults to 50%.

Comment: Seems _cmd_ related. It does have I/O, so maybe try `ProcessBuilder` instead and fiddle with `inheritIO` or such. I cannot imagine alternatives: powershell?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - It sets the maximum heap size to that, but it won't set the initial size of the heap to that.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that you have `_JAVA_OPTS` set in the environment.  But you would get warnings ...

Comment: How are you measuring "consumed" memory?  And when "Visual VM profiler says that there is heap size about 500MB" ... is that the current heap size or the max heap size?

Comment: There is nothing else in the JVM. And also there ist nothing running in the command prompt.

Processbuilder is the same like Runtime.exec, you can look in the api code. Powershell would be maybe a workaround. 

_JAVA_OPTS is not set on the maschines. 

Cosumed in the task manager for the java process. Visual VM just says heap size 500 MB and used heap size about 13 MB.